# How can I get UserPool details by IdentityPool/UserPool id (sub)

Tags: aws-sdk, amazon-cognito, aws-sdk-js

Is there a way to get user details (profile attributes etc) if I have IdentityPool or UserPool ID (sub) of a user with AWS SDK?

The use case is that I'm saving some information submitted by a user in a DB with a key equal to user ID (sub). So, when I'm reading it from the DB, I want to restore back some user info from my pool for my app UI.

I found a similar question ([Getting cognito user pool username from cognito identity pool identityId](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59567546/getting-cognito-user-pool-username-from-cognito-identity-pool-identityid?rq=1)), but it seems, the answer given is focused around serverless deployment, and still has some gaps.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Since you have the user's `sub`, you can use [AdminGetUser](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito-user-identity-pools/latest/APIReference/API_AdminGetUser.html). It returns the `UserAttributes` in the pool.

Answer (score 0):

I think I found a solution, it was on the surface actually.

Having user pool id one can use `ListUsers` call with filter `sub = \"${userId}\"`. The client to be used is `CognitoIdentityProviderClient`, if JS is used.

```js
    const client = new CognitoIdentityProviderClient({
        region: REGION,
        credentials: fromCognitoIdentityPool({
            client: new CognitoIdentityClient({ region: REGION }),
            logins: {
                [PROVIDER_ID]: token
            },
            identityPoolId: ID_POOL_ID
        })
    });

    const filter = `sub = \"${userPoolId}\"`;

    const resp = await client.send(new ListUsersCommand({
        UserPoolId: USER_POOL_ID,
        Filter: filter,
        Limit: 1
    }));
```

Of course AdminGetUser can be used as well, as Ulas Keles mentioned above, if it's applicable